# Using Commands in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have been using the very nice example code from [ApuntasNotas](http://apuntanotas.codeplex.com/) to learn more about how to effectively use the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).

In the code, in one instance, the author seems to make use of the code behind just to set the DataContext for the purpose of handling a click event, which I find confusing.

In the XAML, the `EditNote_Click` event handler for a MenuItem in the ContextMenu `cm` is handled in the code-behind:

```
    <Window x:Class="ApuntaNotas.MainWindow" Icon="Icons/app_48.ico"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="Apunta Notas"
            Height="480"
            x:Name="Ventana"
            Width="640"
            Background="Beige"
            DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
.
.
.
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl Background="Beige" Padding="15" Tag="Hello" x:Name="IC"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}">
                <ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Value, ElementName=zoomSlider}" ScaleY="{Binding Value, ElementName=zoomSlider}" />
                </ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
                <ItemsControl.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu Name="icCM">
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocStrings}, Path=DeleteAllNotes}" Command="{Binding DeleteAllNotesCommand}" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ItemsControl.ContextMenu>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu Name="cm">
                                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocStrings}, Path=Edit}" Click="EditNote_Click"/>
                                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocStrings}, Path=Delete}" Click="DeleteNote_Click" />
                                    <Separator />
                                    <ComboBox Loaded="CmbNoteCategory_Loaded" SelectionChanged="CmbNoteCategory_SelectionChanged">
                                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ComboBox>
                                </ContextMenu>
.
.
.
```

In the code-behind, the `EditNote_Click` handler is defined as follows:

```
private void EditNote_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var menuItem = e.Source as MenuItem;
            if (menuItem != null)
                ViewModel.EditNoteCommand.Execute(menuItem.DataContext as Model.Note);
        }
```

`EditNoteCommand` has the following signature:

```
public RelayCommand<Note> EditNoteCommand { get; private set; }
```

My question is, why wouldn't the author have linked the `EditNoteCommand` command - which is already written and available - to the `Command` attribute of the `MenuItem` in the XAML?

For example, I tried to substitute the following, which compiled, but generated an exception (as shown below).  I suspect that my approach is sound, but that I am missing something about passing a DataContext, or perhaps something else, to the command code.  I reset the DataContext Binding to `Main` to facilitate the command binding:

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocStrings}, Path=Edit}" DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Command="{Binding EditNoteCommand}"/>
```

This attempt generates the following exception in reference to `other` within `EditNote` - a method called by `EditNoteCommand`:

EditNote:

```
private void EditNote(Note other)
        {
            ActualNote = other;
            SelectedCategory = other.Category;
        }
```

Exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled   Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   Source=ApuntaNotas   StackTrace:
       at ApuntaNotas.ViewModel.MainViewModel.EditNote(Note other) in C:\Documents and Settings\wcatlan\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ApuntaNotas\trunk\ApuntaNotas\ViewModel\MainViewModel.cs:line 171
       at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand`1.Execute(Object parameter)
       at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)
       at System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.InvokeClickAfterRender(Object arg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at ApuntaNotas.App.Main() in C:\Documents and Settings\wcatlan\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ApuntaNotas\trunk\ApuntaNotas\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() InnerException:
```

Comment: We probably didn't need the full stack trace. :)

Comment: I see no problem with the full stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track regarding not wanting to use the code-behind unless needed - so keep following that principal in your MVVM and you'll do well.

I think you'll find the author here is using the code-behind to work around a problem with getting the command parameter correct. 
For the edit note command - the view model of the note being edited is the required parameter. Which is what they are doing in code behind here -

```
menuItem.DataContext as Model.Note
```

The problem your having is about getting access to the menu item that was clicked and to the 'main' view model in the same command.

If you were to move the `EditNoteCommand` into the NotesViewModel (or whichever class Notes is) you could keep your command in XAML with something like :

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocStrings}, Path=Edit}" Command="{Binding EditNoteCommand}" />
```

HTH,
Scott

Comment: @Phil - you should have edited the answer to fix the spelling.  Then someone with the appropriate level of rep would have come along and approved your changes.  Remember, you can do that, now.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  Model.Note is the model for a Note, not the viewmodel.  Note actually does not have a viewmodel.  Would the fact that Model.Note is a model, and not a viewmodel, change your analysis?  FWIW, Notes is just an ObservableCollection<Note>.

Comment: @Bill - Welcome Bill - I think Note would be an top candidate for having a VM now even if it was just a model before. Particularly as it will now have commanding, and no doubt INotifyPropertyChanged implementation just around the corner (for updating the UI once the edit is over).

Comment: Thanks again Scott.  Your extra insight on when a Model object, or other object, might "graduate" to warranting a ViewModel is very helpful to me.  If you can think of any other rule of thumb guidelines, or references, for mapping UI elements to ViewModels, it would be more than welcome.